# Background Audio Media Element Android Xamrian Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Ok So I watched this video and it showed me how to do background audio in ios but how does one do the same using the mediaelement control in andriod does anybody have a solution.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XVjsUO-Ayw

```
<xct:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement"
    Grid.Row="0"
    HeightRequest="500"
    AutoPlay="True"
    Volume="1"                          
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
/>
```

In  IOS am placing

```
public void EnableBackgroundAudioPlaying()
{
     var currentStatus = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
     currentStatus.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
     currentStatus.SetActive(true);
}
```

But when I USE the android simulator the audio disconnects when i press the home button.

Comment: That is specific to android Xamarin  Jason this is Xamarin forms big difference a google search does not bring the right solution using with media element part of the xct

Comment: Please read the details before just pasting a comment media element is totally different to xamrain android and as such doesnt use the code thats posted.

Comment: This is a known enhencement about Media Element, you can follow it up here:
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/576

Comment: Doesnt seem to be much chatter on that thread as XCT upgrades wont be hapening cause of MAUI

Comment: Sorry for the trouble for you, we just have to wait patiently for the Xamarin development team to evaluate and solve this problem.